# Loop ajax request -> mysql -> create paragraph

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, loops, createelement

I've read as much as I can, but totally stuck here (had it working at one stage but only if I put alerts in - ??). What I need:

- User inputs a list into a textarea.
- text area read to array.
- ajax requests to php script for each element in array.
- php script then runs a mysql query and returns the result to ajax.
- ajax then creates a new element and fills it with the response.

Hopefully the user will see a list being built as the results come through (the tables are quite large so expecting some data to take longer than others).

Code so far:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function ajaxFunction(value){
    var ajaxRequest;

    try{
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            return ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "results.php?list=" + value, true);
    ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
}

function loopAJAX() {
    var box = document.getElementById("results-table");
    box.innerHTML = "";

    var vars = document.getElementById('list').value;
    var varArray = vars.split("\n");
    var len = varArray.length;

    for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        var text = ajaxFunction(varArray[i]);
        var entry = document.createElement('p');
        entry.innerHTML = text; 
        box.appendChild(entry);
    }
}
</script>
```

Output should be like:

```
<div id='results-table'><p>id1</p><p>id2</p></div>
```

Currently the output looks like:

```
<div id='results-table'><p>undefined</p><p>undefined</p></div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `XMLHTTPRequest`s you are doing are asynchronous, so they cannot return the text at function definition time (they are called later). What you need to do is pass a reference to your `<p>` tag to the `onreadystatechange` method and then update the `innerHTML` inside the callback:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
function ajaxFunction(value, p){
    var ajaxRequest;

    try{
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            p.className = "";
            p.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "results.php?list=" + value, true);
    ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
}

function loopAJAX() {
    var box = document.getElementById("results-table");
    box.innerHTML = "";

    var vars = document.getElementById('list').value;
    var varArray = vars.split("\n");
    var len = varArray.length;

    for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        var entry = document.createElement('p');
        entry.className = "loading";
        entry.innerHTML = "Loading..."; 
        var text = ajaxFunction(varArray[i],entry);
        box.appendChild(entry);
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fundamentally broken. An AJAX call is asychronous - your `ajaxFunction()` returns IMMEDIATELY, without waiting for the server response. That means it's returning a null value to the rest of your code, which you then insert into the document, causing your "undefined" paragraphs.

To fix this code, you must have the onreadystatechange handler call a function which inserts the returned data - this will happen only AFTER the server responds with some data.

Beyond that, your code is highly inefficient. You're doing an ajax call for every item the user enters. There's absolutely no reason why you couldn't modify your PHP script to accept MULTIPLE values, process them all at once, and return all the results in a single call.

Comment: Thanks!(this is very early stage development - just learning). I can make them all returned in a single call, but the mysql has to have them separate so I thought it would be nice to have the results returning as they get collected by the mysql :D

Comment: basically (in hackishly bad pseudocode): `sample.php?ids=1,2,3,4,5`, then you can do `select ... from ... where id in (1,2,3,4,5); echo json_encode($result_array)`

Comment: It's a cleaner solution, I agree. However, that query in this particular database would take a long time, so I was hoping to get results as they were available (records into the billions).